# How can I set the default orientation of labview windows?

Tags: layout, keyboard-shortcuts, labview

Whenever I open a new labview project, it opens two small windows, one for the block diagram and the front panel. Since using labview effectively requires simultaneous use of both, is it possible to set things up such that, upon starting a new VI, it opens these two windows in pre-determined positions and sizes?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know setting to do so (and think there is no such setting), but your problem is easily solvable if you press ctrl+t when new vi is opened.

ctrl+t will set front panel on the left half part of the screen and block diagram on the right part. Pressing ctrl+t a second time will set the panel to top half and diagram to the bottom half.

[Shortcuts In LabVIEW](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/lvhowto/keyboard_shortcuts/)

Comment: This is definitely good enough to work with. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also if the answer solves the problem, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround:

1. Create a new empty VI
2. Resize and reposition the front panel window as you wish
3. Do the same for the block diagram window
4. Save the VI as a **template** (.vit)
5. Double click the template to use it (position and size of windows will be as they were when saving)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you want to be doing manually everytime. You can press WIN+LEFT on one of the windows and WIN+RIGHT on the other. This will evenly distribute the two windows over the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can set window position for individual VIs by pressing `Ctrl`+`I` to open the VI properties, and setting the desired appearance under "Window Size"